# Unity - why is output_log.txt not showing filenames in errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have been having some problems with the build of my game. Everything works fine in the editor but as soon as I build the game, one of the main functions doesn't work. In output_log.txt there is an error that shows, but It doesn't tell me what it's from:

(Filename:  Line: 1775)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '') is missing!

Can anyone tell me why?

using unity 2018.2, and am running windows 8

Comment: Can we have more information? Build logs or something?

Comment: Ok sorry I’ll add some more information, I don’t have time right now but I’ll edit it in soon

Answer (score 0):

Two years late, I know:

Go to Build Settings and check Development Build and Script Debugging.